# How to paste many "nodes" of text into one single text?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have webscraped this https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2019/html/ecb.is190912~658eb51d68.en.html. The problem is that the text is divided into as many paragraphs as SelectorGadget selected. Instead, I would like it to be one single text.

I have the following code that you can replicate to better understand the problem:

```
url_ecb_190124 <- "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2019/html/ecb.is190124~cd3821f8f5.en.html"

    ecb_190124 <- read_html(url_ecb_190124)

statements1 <- html_text(html_nodes(ecb_190124, ".ecb-pressCategory~ p+ p"))
```

Unfortunately, "statements1" takes [86] paraghraps (86 obs.), whereas I just want it to be one single observation. I tried without results all the commands I am ware of ("paste", "rbind", etc.).

Does anyone know how I can sort it out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `paste`

```r
paste(statements1, collapse = "")
```

when you add the collapse parameter it combines all elements in a vector and separates them with what you put in the quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using "paste" in the wrong way: `paste(statements1[1:86], collpase = " ")` In this way it did not work. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `toString`

```
toString(statements1)
```

Comment: Didn't know about it, thanks a lot! It works just fine :)